# Find a way in a train timetable and get change-stations with line-nr

Tags: algorithm, search, prolog

I'm trying to find a way in a train timetable and get the change-station and the line-nr. But I'm getting some trouble when you have to change train. First here's the code and a (long) snippet from the timetable database.

#### The Database

```
%Linie 3A (Richtung Wiler Mann) 
%          lineNr, A,B,time(minute)
verbindung('3A',[pirnaischer, platz], [albertplatz], [18, 28, 38, 48, 58, 08]).
verbindung('3A',[albertplatz], [bahnhof, neustadt], [23, 33, 43, 53, 03, 13]).
verbindung('3A',[bahnhof, neustadt], [hansastraße], [25, 35, 45, 55, 05, 15]).
verbindung('3A',[hansastraße], [liststraße], [26, 36, 46, 56, 06, 16]).
verbindung('3A',[liststraße], [trachenberger, platz], [30, 40, 50, 00, 10, 20]).
verbindung('3A',[trachenberger, platz], [hubertusplatz], [33, 43, 53, 03, 13, 23]).
verbindung('3A',[hubertusplatz], [wilder, mann], [35, 45, 55, 05, 15, 25]).
verbindung('3A',[wilder, mann], [xxx1], [38, 48, 58, 08, 18, 28]). 
%xxx ist hier damit man auch die ankuftszeiten an der Enthaltestelle angeben kann.

%Linie 3B = Linie 3 Richtung coschütz
verbindung('3B',[wilder, mann],[hubertusplatz], [04, 14, 24, 34, 44, 54]). 
verbindung('3B',[hubertusplatz],[trachenberger, platz], [06, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56]).
verbindung('3B',[trachenberger, platz],[liststraße], [08, 18, 28, 38, 48, 58]).
verbindung('3B',[liststraße],[hansastraße], [11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 01]).
verbindung('3B',[hansastraße], [bahnhof, neustadt], [14, 24, 34, 44, 54, 04]).
verbindung('3B',[bahnhof, neustadt], [albertplatz],[16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 06]).
verbindung('3B',[albertplatz], [pirnaischer, platz], [18, 28, 38, 48, 58, 08]).
verbindung('3B',[pirnaischer, platz], [xxx2], [23, 33, 43, 53, 03, 13]).

%Linie 1 (Richtung leutewitz)
verbindung('1A',[pirnaischer, platz],[postplatz],[31,41,51,01,11,21]).
verbindung('1A',[postplatz],[bahnhof, mitte],[34,44,54,04,14,24]).
verbindung('1A',[bahnhof, mitte],[waltherstraße],[38,48,58,08,18,28]).
verbindung('1A',[waltherstraße],[flügelweg],[42,52,02,12,22,32]).
verbindung('1A',[flügelweg],[gottfried-keller-straße],[45,55,05,15,25,35]).
verbindung('1A',[gottfried-keller-straße],[leutewitz],[48,58,08,18,28,38]).
verbindung('1A',[leutewitz],[xxx3],[50,00,10,20,30,40]).

%Linie 1 (Richtung prohlis, schleife)
verbindung('1B',[leutewitz],[gottfried-keller-straße],[04,14,24,34,44,54]).
verbindung('1B',[gottfried-keller-straße],[flügelweg],[06,16,26,36,46,56]).
verbindung('1B',[flügelweg],[waltherstraße],[09,19,29,39,49,59]).
verbindung('1B',[waltherstraße],[bahnhof, mitte],[12,22,32,42,52,02]).
verbindung('1B',[bahnhof, mitte],[postplatz],[17,27,37,47,57,07]).
verbindung('1B',[postplatz],[altmarkt],[21,31,41,51,01,11]).
verbindung('1B',[altmarkt],[pirnaischer, platz],[22,32,42,52,02,12]).
verbindung('1B',[pirnaischer, platz],[xxx4],[24,34,44,54,04,14]).

%Linie94
verbindung('94A',[postplatz],[bahnhof, mitte],[07, 27, 47]).
verbindung('94A',[bahnhof, mitte],[krankenhaus, friedrichstadt],[11, 31, 51]).
verbindung('94A',[krankenhaus, friedrichstadt],[waltherstraße],[14, 34, 54]).
verbindung('94A',[waltherstraße],[flügelweg],[17, 37, 57]).
verbindung('94A',[flügelweg],[gottfried-geller-straße],[20, 40, 50]).
verbindung('94A',[gottfried-keller-straße],[zschonergrundstraße],[23, 43, 03]).
verbindung('94A',[zschonergrundstraße],[am, urnenfeld],[27, 47, 07]).
verbindung('94A',[am, urnenfeld],[ludwigstraße],[32, 52, 12]).
verbindung('94A',[ludwigstraße],[erna-berger-straße],[35, 55, 15]).
verbindung('94A',[erna-berger-straße],[cossebaude, bahnhof],[37, 57, 17]).
verbindung('94A',[cossebaude, bahnhof],[xxx9],[38, 58, 18]).
```

#### The search predicate

```
dlDfs(Node, Goal, Path,LinienPath,UmstiegPath, LinienLimit, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg) :-
    Node = Goal,
    reverse(Path, ReturnPath),
    reverse(LinienPath, ReturnLinie),
    reverse(UmstiegPath, ReturnUmstieg)
    ;
    0 =< LinienLimit,
    verbindung(Linie,Node,NewNeighbor,_),
    not(member(NewNeighbor,Path)),
    (
        (
            not(member(Linie, LinienPath)), NewLinienLimit is LinienLimit - 1,
            dlDfs(NewNeighbor, Goal, [NewNeighbor|Path], [Linie|LinienPath], [Node|UmstiegPath], NewLinienLimit, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg)
        )
    ;
        (dlDfs(NewNeighbor, Goal, [NewNeighbor|Path], LinienPath, UmstiegPath, LinienLimit, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie,ReturnUmstieg)
    )).

idDfsLoop(Start, Goal,L, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg) :-
    dlDfs(Start, Goal, [Start],[], [], L, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg)
    ;
    L1 is L + 1,
    idDfsLoop(Start, Goal, L1, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg).

idDfs(Start, Goal, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg) :-
    idDfsLoop(Start, Goal, 1, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg),
    !.
```

If I try to find a way from "albertplatz" to "erna-berger-straße" for example, I have to change train-line 3 times. 
Now, when I call

```
 idDfs([albertplatz], [erna-berger-straße], Path, ChangeLine,
 ChangeStop).
```

the programm should return

```
 Path = [The hole Path],
 ChangeLine = ['3B', '1A', '94A'],
 ChangeStop[[albertplatz],[pirnaischer,platz], [...]].
```

But I only get

```
 Path = [The hole Path], 
 ChangeLine = ['3B', '94A'],   
 ChangeLine = [[albertplatz], [am, urnenfeld]].
```

And I don't know why. If I test the way from [albertplatz] to [postplatz] the program returns me the right answer, maybe because there is only one change-stop.

### EDIT:

Thanks to @SQB's help I fixed my problem, here is the new working search predicate

#### Search predicate - solution

```
dlDfs(Goal, Goal, Path, LinienPath, CurrentLine, UmstiegPath, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg) :-
    reverse(Path, ReturnPath),
    reverse(LinienPath, ReturnLinie),
    reverse(UmstiegPath, ReturnUmstieg).


dlDfs(Node, Goal, Path, LinienPath, CurrentLine, UmstiegPath,  ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg) :-
    verbindung(CurrentLine, Node, NewNeighbor,_),
    not(member(NewNeighbor, Path)),
    (
        not(member(CurrentLine, LinienPath)),
        dlDfs(NewNeighbor, Goal, [NewNeighbor|Path], [CurrentLine|LinienPath], CurrentLine, [Node|UmstiegPath], ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg)
    ;
        dlDfs(NewNeighbor, Goal, [NewNeighbor|Path], LinienPath, CurrentLine, UmstiegPath, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie,ReturnUmstieg)
    ).

dlDfs(Node, Goal, Path, LinienPath, CurrentLine, UmstiegPath, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg) :-
    verbindung(Linie, Node, NewNeighbor,_),
    not(Linie == CurrentLine),
    not(member(NewNeighbor, Path)),
    not(member(Linie, LinienPath)),
    dlDfs(NewNeighbor, Goal, [NewNeighbor|Path], [Linie|LinienPath], Linie, [Node|UmstiegPath], ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg).
```

Comment: A problem I noticed right away is that you're calling `idDfsLoop` with `L+1` as its third argument somewhere. Know that this is **not** evaluated, but rather concatenated. In other words, if `L=1`, the called predicate will see _literally_ `1+1` as its L, then `1+1+1` the next time it's called, and so on. Instead, do something like `L1 is L + 1` and use `L1` as the argument.

Comment: I changed the code with the suggestion from @SQB for `L` and for  `LinienLimit`. Unfortunately it's the same output.

Comment: I've edited your code further. These changes are _probably_ what you've done already and just copied incorrectly; if you _haven't_ done it like this, you probably should try doing so.

Comment: I've done it like in your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `dlDfs/9`, which I took the liberty of splitting up.

```
dlDfs(Goal, Goal, Path, LinienPath, UmstiegPath, _LinienLimit, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg) :-
    reverse(Path, ReturnPath),
    reverse(LinienPath, ReturnLinie),
    reverse(UmstiegPath, ReturnUmstieg).

dlDfs(Node, Goal, Path, LinienPath, UmstiegPath, LinienLimit, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg) :-
    0 =< LinienLimit,
    verbindung(Linie, Node, NewNeighbor,_),
    not(member(NewNeighbor, Path)),
    (
        not(member(Linie, LinienPath)),
        NewLinienLimit is LinienLimit - 1,
        dlDfs(NewNeighbor, Goal, [NewNeighbor|Path], [Linie|LinienPath], [Node|UmstiegPath], NewLinienLimit, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie, ReturnUmstieg)
    ;
        dlDfs(NewNeighbor, Goal, [NewNeighbor|Path], LinienPath, UmstiegPath, LinienLimit, ReturnPath, ReturnLinie,ReturnUmstieg)
    ).
```

The problem lies in the second one. You do some checks, then you have two paths to take. The first is if the new `Linie` is not already in `LinienPath` (interesting mix of English and German, by the way). You decrease the `LinienLimit` and call dlDfs again.
*However*, if that fails, for instance because the `LinienLimit` drops below 0, the second path is taken, where the new found node is still added to the path, but the line is not added to the list of lines — *even if it's a new line*.

What you need to do, I think, is not just check if the line is in the list of lines already taken, but also if the line you found your connection on is the line you're currently riding.

My advice would be to split your predicates over several clauses, instead of using semi-colons. Then, for `dlDfs`, you have several cases, which you need to define.

1. You've found your goal. That's the one I've already split off.
2. You find a new connection riding the same line you're already on.
3. You find a new connection, but it's on a line you haven't ridden before.

---

A totally different way of doing this, would be to check which line your start is on, which line your goal is on, and how to connect those lines.
That is how humans would do it: "ah yes, the Erna Bergerstraße is on line 94, I'm now at Albertplatz which is on line 3, let's see, these lines aren't connected, but I can change at Pirnaischer Platz to get on line 1, and again at Ludwigstrasse to get on line 94 to go to the Erna Bergerstraße."

---

Also, you've misspelled "gottfried-keller-straße" once.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it fixed the problem! I updated my question with the right answer.